# Use CUDA driver API in host code which contains CUDA runtime API

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to use CUDA driver API if my program already contains Runtime API?
In other words, is it possible to use driver API and runtime APi side-by-side?This is because driver API provides good control to device but at the same time runtime API facilitates coding!

Comment: Yes this has been possible since about CUDA 3.0

Comment: Great! Can you direct me to some PDF/guide/blog which has such example?

Comment: Appendix G4 of the programming guide should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can even use handles for objects such as CUDA streams and events interchangeably.